# Matlab, generate new matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

How do you translate matrix of A [(N) x (N)] to matrix B [(2N) x (2N)], such that:

```
if A(i,j)>=0, then:
B(i,j) = [ A(i,j) 0
           0      A(i,j)]

if A(i,j)<0, then:
B(i,j) = [ 0       A(i,j)
           A(i,j)  0    ]

?
```

For example1 by:

```
1  2
3  4
```

I'm want to get:

```
1 0 2 0
0 1 0 2
3 0 4 0
0 3 0 4
```

For example2 by:

```
1  -2
3  -4
```

I'm want to get:

```
1 0 0 2
0 1 2 0
3 0 0 4
0 3 4 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Kronecker tensor product](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
B = kron(A.*(A>=0), [1 0; 0 1]) + kron(A.*(A<0), [0 1; 1 0]);
```

Or maybe

```
B = kron(A.*(A>=0), [1 0; 0 1]) - kron(A.*(A<0), [0 1; 1 0]);
```

if you want all positive values (your examples and your original formulation don't agree on this)

Comment: yep, that's what the OP wanted I guess, shame he didn't ask for it in the first place.

Comment: change to  `kron(A.*(A>=0), [1 0; 0 1])  - kron(A.*(A<0), [0 1; 1 0])` to fit to what OP really wanted...

Comment: @natan Thanks! The text and the examples don't agree. A confusing question indeed

Comment: now I have a question for SE Meta... should I delete my answer or not... :-)

Comment: @natan I would keep it, but I would add a text at the beginning explaining how you interpreted the question

Comment: @LuisMendo: You strike again!  I didn't know about `kron`

Answer (score 1):

very simple using logical conditions:

```
B=[A.*(A>=0), A.*(A<0) ; A.*(A<0), A.*(A>=0)];
```

for example,

```
A=[1 2 ; -3 4];

B =

 1     2     0     0
 0     4    -3     0
 0     0     1     2
-3     0     0     4
```

---

### Postscipt:

This answer was written to answer the question above in its initial forms:

```
How do you translate matrix of A [(N) x (N)] to matrix B [(2N) x (2N)], such that:

if A(i,j)>=0, then:
B(i,j) = [ A(i,j) 0
           0      A(i,j)]

if A(i,j)<0, then:
B(i,j) = [ 0       A(i,j)
           A(i,j)  0    ]

?
```

later the OP wrote down some examples that made clear what he\she were after.

Comment: No, it generate 98x1:
`x=7; y=7;

A = rand(x,y);

B=[A(A>0), A(A<0) ; A(A<0), A(A>0)];`

Comment: This is wrong too...
This generate 2N x 2N, but format is:
1 2 0 0
3 4 0 0
0 0 1 2
0 0 3 4
But

Comment: @user3466022 in any case you can be more polite and patient when others try to solve your problem and help you

Comment: 4 example:

`1  2`


`3  4`

This generate 2N x 2N, but format is:
`1 2 0 0`


`3 4 0 0`


`0 0 1 2`


`0 0 3 4`

But i'm want:
`1 0 2 0`


`0 1 0 2`


`3 0 4 0`


`0 3 0 4`

Comment: obviously we don't understand one another. Please edit the question itself, make it clear and accurate instead of using the comments. For example `B(i,j)=[A(i,j) 0 ; 0 A(i,j)]` is problematic in notation, since they cant share the same `[i,j]` if B is twice bigger than A... Last, try to understand the answer instead of trying to be served with a solution that you haven't asked for.

Comment: well, I understand now, the notation you used at the beginning means something different (that is what I answered).  Luis Mendo already gave you the answer.